# VBA Averageifs With Boolean Triggers

Tags: excel, vba, flags

I am trying to do averageif calculations based on these boolean triggers across 75,000 rows in an efficient manner.

See below I have now tried to use the flag to calculate an average if but it's not working - can anyone suggest where I am going wrong? Also, is using Averageifs is to processor intensive and should I be using a different method? Thanks

```
Sub segment_trigger_returns()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim segment_trigger As Boolean
Dim data_set As Variant
data_set = Range("A4:AV75617")
alpha_1y = Range("S4:S759617")
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To UBound(data_set, 1)
company_name_curperiod = data_set(i, 3)
company_name_prevperiod = data_set(i - 1, 3)
segments_curperiod = data_set(i, 10)
segments_prevperiod = data_set(i - 1, 10)
If company_name_curperiod = company_name_prevperiod And segments_curperiod <> segments_prevperiod Then
segment_trigger = True
Else: segment_trigger = False
End If
Next i
Sheets("Control").Range("K6") = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(alpha_1y, segment_trigger = True)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to declare `alpha_1y` - it should be a `Range` and should be `Set` too. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.

Comment: `segment_trigger = True` seems redundant: `True = True` is just `True`, and similarly for `False = True`.